# MongoDB - join 2 collections with $lookup in array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following sample document in collection called fieldlist

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5de3aafd2e46e531a45e441a"),
    "version" : 1,
    "isvalid" : true,
    "columnname_datatype" : 
    {
        "col1" : "number",
        "col2" : "string",
        "col3" : "string",
        "col4" : "date"
    },
    "last_updated_by" : ObjectId("5dc0aed15399202590f34a54")
}
```

In "columnname_datatype" sub-document, its keys col1, col2, etc. could be different (dynamic in nature) based on user input.

and 2nd collection fieldlistvalues with following sample document:

```
{
    "_id" : "test_data1",
    "name" : "Test Data version 1",
    "fieldlist_version" : ObjectId("5de3aafd2e46e531a45e441a"),
    "last_updated_date" : ISODate("2014-10-11T18:59:06.313+05:30"),
    "fieldlistarray" : [
        {
            "PKid" : "4902121027",
            "first_release_value" : 2014.67,
            "production_values" : [
                73,
                18309,
                12636
            ],
            "col1" : 13431.666666666666,
            "real_time_data" : {

            },
            "col5" : null,
            "status" : "ACTIVE",
            "col2" : "JULESBURG",
            "col3" : "EOG RES",
            "col4" : "03/15/2015"
        },
        {
            "PKid" : "4202121786",
            "first_release_value" : 14.41667,
            "olddata" : [
                204.8333333333333,
                2009.9166666666667
            ],
            "production_values" : [
                1945,
                762,
                315,
                957
            ],
            "col1" : 775.3333333333334,
            "status" : "INACTIVE",
            "col2" : "Not Available",
            "col3" : "CIRQUE, LP",
            "di_status" : "P & A",
            "col4" : "12/15/2020"
        },
    "miscdata" : [
        {
            "method" : null,
            "event_start_indices" : [
                    1,
                    10,
                    22
                ],
            "types" : "misc",
            "result" : 0
        }
        ]
    ]
}
```

I am looking for following output

```
{col1: [13431.666666666666, 775.3333333333334]},
{col2: ["JULESBURG", "Not Available"]},
{col3: ["EOG RES", "CIRQUE, LP"]},
{col4: [03/15/2015, 12/15/2020]}
```

Tried using $lookup with let & pipeline directly with an array (fieldlistarray[] in this case) But didn't get desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection('fieldlist').aggregate([{
  $lookup:{
    from:"fieldlistvalues",
    localField:"_id",
    foreignField:"fieldlist_version",
    as:"column_data"
  }
},
{
   $unwind:"$column_data"
},
{
   $unwind:"$column_data.fieldlistarray"
},
{
   $group:{
       _id:"$_id",
       col1:{$push:"$column_data.fieldlistarray.col1"},
       col2:{$push:"$column_data.fieldlistarray.col2"},
       col3:{$push:"$column_data.fieldlistarray.col3"},
       col4:{$push:"$column_data.fieldlistarray.col4"}
   }
},
{
    $project:{
       _id:0
}
}])
```

Comment: It looks like it should work, will try and post result back. Thank you. Also, if my field/key names changes in fieldlist collection say from col1, 2, 3.. to  col20, col21 can we somehow make above dynamic using $column_data.fieldlistarray.k